# Regex to test whether there are more than two digits in a string

Tags: regex, password-protection

As far as I know, `\d{2,}` matches 2 or more consecutive digits, but I need to know whether there are any 2 digits in a string.

I would also appreciate some good links to password strength meters.

What I use now is

```
function passwordStrengthPercent(pwd,username)
{
    var score = 0, special = /(.*[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,;,:,`,|,\\,\/,<,>,\{,\},\[,\],=,\+])/
    if (pwd.length < 8 ) return 0
    if (pwd.toLowerCase() == username.toLowerCase()) return -1
    score += pwd.length * 4
    score += ( checkRepetition(1,pwd).length - pwd.length )
    score += ( checkRepetition(2,pwd).length - pwd.length )
    score += ( checkRepetition(3,pwd).length - pwd.length )
    score += ( checkRepetition(4,pwd).length - pwd.length )
    if (pwd.match(/(.*[e].*[e].*[e])/))  score -= 15//most common letter in passswords?
    if (pwd.match(/(.*[a].*[a].*[a])/))  score -= 15//most common letter in passswords?
    if (pwd.match(/(.*[o].*[o].*[o])/))  score -= 10//most common letter in passswords?
    if (pwd.match(/^\l+$/) || pwd.match(/^\d+$/) )  return score/2//there was w here in regexp
    if (pwd.match(/(.*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9])/))  score += 10

    //todo additional rules 11
    if (pwd.match(special)) score += 15
    if (pwd.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/))  score += 15
    if (pwd.match(/(w)/) && pwd.match(/(d)/))  score += 15
    if (pwd.match(special) && pwd.match(/(d)/))  score += 10
    if (pwd.match(special) && pwd.match(/(w)/))  score += 10
    if ( score < 0 ) return 0
    if ( score > 100 ) return 100
  return score
}
```

Comment: Here's a meter - http://www.passwordmeter.com/

Comment: `d` matches a literal letter d. You want `\d` instead.

Comment: Here's another meter: https://www.grc.com/haystack.htm

Comment: [You should take a look at this, by the way.](http://xkcd.com/936/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
^.*\d.*\d.*$
```

which will only match if (at least) two digits are included.

Comment: But since he needs at least two, he has to check for one and two?

Comment: You don't need the `^.*` and `.*$` parts.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```
\d.*\d
```

That matches two numerals anywhere in the line, even with other characters between them.

Comment: +1 Or better yet: `/\d\D*\d/` (The all-powerful dot is rarely necessary or the most efficient choice - _"Say what you mean, mean what you say!"_)

Answer (score 0):

check if there are ***Exactly*** two digits:

```
^[^\d]*\d[^\d]*\d[^\d]*$
```

see the test with grep:

```
kent$  echo "23
2   3
ax3x2x
aaaaa23
a222
2
3x3x4
3 4 5"|grep -P "^[^\d]*\d[^\d]*\d[^\d]*$"                                                                                                
23
2   3
ax3x2x
aaaaa23
```